# Changing the background image size, but not the background color

Tags: html, css, background-image

I wanted to have a background that has a gradient color and also a background image. It's just a transparent icon, but I wanted to change the size of the icon itself without affecting the actual background size.

Thanks for any help!!

```css
 .bg {
 background:url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/announcement-icon.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#1cd0d0 10%, #79dcc5 80%, #3bbdb18c 100%); 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  hi
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Im not 100% clear on what you want to achieve, but maybe just put the icon and the text each into a new container, put them in a wrapper and set the icon's position to absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `background:` definintion has two backgrounds setup. You can attach the `background-size` to the first definition, but it needs to be written as `position/scale`:

```css
.bg {
 background: 
 url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/announcement-icon.png) no-repeat center/30%, 
 linear-gradient(#1cd0d0 10%, #79dcc5 80%, #3bbdb18c 100%);

 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  hi
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```